# iPhone Device 3.1 SDK Breaks vertical alignment of UITableViewCellStyleValue1 textLabel

Tags: iphone, uitableview

**Can anyone provide an explanation for the following phenomenon?**

As of the iPhone Device 3.1 SDK, I've found that if a `UITableViewCell` is of style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` and its `detailTextLabel.text` is unassigned, then the `textLabel` does not display in the center of the cell as would be expected.

One notable caveat is that this only happens for me when I'm testing on the *Device* – the iPhone *Simulator* 3.1 SDK displays the cells correctly. Also, this is not a problem when using the iPhone Device 3.0 SDK.

Below is a simple `UITableViewController` subclass implementation that demonstrates the problem.

```
@implementation BuggyTableViewController

#pragma mark Table view methods


// Customize the number of rows in the table view.
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 3;
}


// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    switch (indexPath.row) {
  case 0:
   cell.textLabel.text = @"detailTextLabel.text unassigned";
   break;
  case 1:
   cell.textLabel.text = @"detailTextLabel.text = @\"\"";
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"";
   break;
  case 2:
   cell.textLabel.text = @"detailTextLabel.text = @\"A\"";
   cell.detailTextLabel.text = @"A";
   break;
  default:
   break;
 }

    return cell;
}

@end
```

Comment: This was in 3.0 as well, you should set the allocate the cell with that style inside of ones you know will have a detailTextLabel, and the default when they aren't.

Comment: I just ran into this one too in 3.1.2. Exactly the same: only on the device. I also notice that the label in the cell shifts into its incorrect position using animation just after the view is revealed. I shot a movie of it doing it just to prove to myself I wasn't imagining it. The workaround of using cell.detailTextLabel.text = @""; fixed it for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

try using

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same problem. The cell looked fine in the simulator but when i ran the app on the device the cell text was not centered vertically. Using UITableViewCellStyleDefault solved my vertical alignment centering problems. Fortunately my cell does not have a subtitle.